# Oracle SQL - select pairs where an index value has its smallest value, EXCEPT when there has already been a previous pair with a smaller value

Tags: sql, oracle, select, data-manipulation

I am trying to select rows from a table where an index column has its minimum value within a partition, under the condition that this row has not already had a match in a previous partition. The selection should work in a kind of draw without replacing-manner.

Maybe it is better to clarify with an example. Consider the following table:

```
ID1   ID2    index
foo   qux    1
foo   quux   2
foo   corge  3
bar   qux    4
bar   quux   5
bar   corge  6
baz   quux   7
baz   corge  8
```

For every group in ID1, starting at the lowest index values, I want to pick the match from ID2 with the minimum index value for this partition (here: `qux` with an in index value of `1`).
Now, for `ID1=bar`, the matching ID2 would be `quux` (with an index value of `5`), since `qux` has already been picked (and matched to `foo`).
Similarly, `baz` would match with `corge`because `quux` was already matched to `bar`.

So the resulting query result should be

```
ID1   ID2   index
foo   qux    1
bar   quux   5
baz   corqe  8
```

Note that not all values in ID1 have all possible values in ID2 and vice versa, also the subgroup sizes in ID1 and ID2 are not constant.

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Edit: the values of ID1 and ID2 don't have any meaning, they are just completely random identifiers. I modified the example to make this clearer.

Edit2: the solution from @p3consulting looked very promising, but it doesn't work with the following data

```
ID1   ID2    index
a1    b1     1
a1    b2     2
a2    b3     3
a4    b4     4
```

where it only delivers `index=1` and not `index=3`.

Answer (score 2):

But also need to keep (id1,id2) with MIN(idx), so eventually :

```
with data(id1, id2, idx)
as
(
    Select 'a1' as ID1, 'b1' as ID2, 1 as "index" from dual
    Union all Select 'a1' as ID1, 'b2' as ID2, 2 as "index" from dual
    Union all Select 'a1' as ID1, 'b3' as ID2, 3 as "index" from dual
    Union all Select 'a2' as ID1, 'b1' as ID2, 4 as "index" from dual
    Union all Select 'a2' as ID1, 'b2' as ID2, 5 as "index" from dual
    Union all Select 'a2' as ID1, 'b3' as ID2, 6 as "index" from dual
    Union all Select 'a2' as ID1, 'b2' as ID2, 8 as "index" from dual
    Union all Select 'a3' as ID1, 'b2' as ID2, 9 as "index" from dual
    Union all Select 'a3' as ID1, 'b3' as ID2, 10 as "index" from dual
)
SELECT id1, id2, idx FROM (
    SELECT d.*, 
        MIN(idx) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY idx) OVER(PARTITION BY id1, id2) AS midx,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY id1) AS rn1
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY id2) AS rn2
    FROM data d
)
WHERE rn1 = rn2 AND idx = midx
ORDER BY idx
;

a1  b1  1
a2  b2  5
a3  b3  10
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
with table_1 
as
(
          Select 'a1' as ID1, 'b1' as ID2, 1 as "index" from dual
Union all Select 'a1' as ID1, 'b2' as ID2, 2 as "index" from dual
Union all Select 'a1' as ID1, 'b3' as ID2, 3 as "index" from dual
Union all Select 'a2' as ID1, 'b1' as ID2, 4 as "index" from dual
Union all Select 'a2' as ID1, 'b2' as ID2, 5 as "index" from dual
Union all Select 'a2' as ID1, 'b3' as ID2, 6 as "index" from dual
Union all Select 'a2' as ID1, 'b2' as ID2, 8 as "index" from dual
)
Select 
    ID1,
    ID2,
    "index"
from
(
Select 
ID1,
ID2,
"index",
rank() over (PARTITION BY ID1 order by "index") rank
from 
    table_1
where
    substr(id1,2,1) = substr(id2,2,1)
)x
where rank = 1
```

Comment: I think you missed the point of the OP's question.  It is just a coincidence that the 2nd position of `ID1` and `ID2` are the same in all rows of his example result set.

Comment: Exactly, I modified the question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but looks like the solution is where

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY id1) AS rn1
, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY id2) AS rn2
```

are equals.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is practical to do in Oracle SQL.  You might get a wizard with extra time on his hands to post something really cool using the `MODEL` clause or similar feature, but if this is practical code that you want other people to be able to read, understand, and maintain, I would do this in PL/SQL.

Here's the general idea (this won't compile exactly, but it's pretty close).

```
DECLARE
  l_rc SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
  -- Mark everything unused to start
  -- You need a "USED" column in your table.
  UPDATE my_table
  SET used = 'N';

  LOOP  
    BEGIN
      SELECT id1, id2, idx
      INTO   l_id1, l_id2, l_idx
      WHERE used = 'N'
      ORDER BY IDX
      FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN no_data_found THEN
        EXIT; -- exit loop
    END;
  
    -- Mark the row as used = 'Y'...these will be in our result set
    UPDATE my_table
    SET    used = 'Y'
    WHERE  idx = l_idx;

    -- Mark all the other occurrences of id2 as 'X' to make them ineligible in
    -- future iterations
    UPDATE my_table
    SET    used = 'X'
    WHERE  used IS NULL
    AND    id2 = l_id2;
  END LOOP;

  OPEN l_rc FOR 
    SELECT id1, id2, idx
    FROM   my_table
    WHERE  used = 'Y'
    ORDER BY idx;
  
  RETURN l_rc;
END;
```

If you really need to provide a SQL API to this logic (i.e., you really want other code to be able to `SELECT` the answer instead of, for example, getting a ref cursor output from a PL/SQL procedure, you can wrap the PL/SQL logic in a pipelined function and, optionally, wrap that in a view.